# Displaying a DialogFragment in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I have a MainActivity (extends activity) and created a DialogFragment in a separate file. In order to show this DialogFragment, do I have to create a FragmentActivity or can I achieve this in MainActivity or should I convert my MainActivity to FragmentActivity? Because the following show function does not work in MainActivity:

```
private void showEditDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    EditNameDialog editNameDialog = new EditNameDialog();
    editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
```

Comment: what does "not work" mean?

Comment: @blackbelt getSupportFragment manager throws an error as "The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity"

Comment: Let your activity extends FragmentActivity

Comment: Is it ok if I have an app without a normal MainActiviy (extends Activity) but a MainActivity extends FragmentActivity? I am completly new = )

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: If I let my MainActivity extends FragmentActivity, I wont have any activity which extends Activity. I have thouhgt every android application should possess a main activity which extends Activity (not FragmentActivity) but probably I am talking nonsense right now

Comment: a FragmentActiviy is an Activity with fragment support. You will have still all the features of an Activity